# Selecting specific nodes in an XML file from multiple levels

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an xml file in a format similar to this:

```
<benchmark>
<group>
    <id>1</id>
    <rule>
        <id>H1234</id>
        <severity>High</severity>
    </rule>
    <title>How to win</title>
</group>
<group>
    <id>2</id>
    <rule>
        <id>5317</id>
        <severity>low</severity>
    </rule>
    <title>How to not</title>
</group>
<group>
    <id>3</id>
    <rule>
        <id>H15678</id>
        <severity>medium</severity>
    </rule>
    <title>How to be</title>
</group>
<group>
    <id>4</id>
    <rule>
        <id>H454</id>
        <severity>High</severity>
    </rule>
    <title>How to lose</title>
</group></benchmark>
```

I would like to be able to select the group/id, group/rule/id, group/rule/severity and group/title values from each group in the xml docoument.

I have tried this but it only gets me part of the way there:

```
I have tried $xml.benchmark.group | %{$_} | select title, id
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$xml.benchmark.group |
select @{ L = 'GroupID';      E = { $_.id } },
       @{ L = 'GroupTitle';   E = { $_.title } },
       @{ L = 'RuleID';       E = { $_.rule.id } },
       @{ L = 'RuleSeverity'; E = { $_.rule.severity } }
```

yielding the following:

```
GroupID GroupTitle  RuleID RuleSeverity
------- ----------  ------ ------------
1       How to win  H1234  High
2       How to not  5317   low
3       How to be   H15678 medium
4       How to lose H454   High
```

The syntax above is similar to SQL's `SELECT Foo AS Bar`, selecting a value (`Expression` or `E` in the hashtable) and providing an alias for display purposes (`Label` or `L` in the hashtable).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with :

```
Clear-Host
$xmlData = [xml](Get-Content c:\temp\fic.xml)
foreach ($group in $xmlData.benchmark.group)
{
  $group.id
  $group.title
  $group.rule.id
}
```

On the command line.

```
([xml](Get-Content C:\temp\fic.xmlfic.xml)).benchmark.group | % {$_.id + " " + $_.rule.id}
```

I hope it helps

JP

Comment: Thank you for trying. I was already pulling the id and title. I needed the id and severity from the lower level nodes as well.

Comment: Here you are, you are not making a lot of effort. I do try ;o)